# Weird list assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write program that will find all [palindromes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindrome) in a word. For example word "radar" has got 2 palindromes `radar` and `ada`. We skip single letters, so `r, a, d`, etc. aren't palindromes.

```
import copy

def ILEP(word):
    lista = list(word)
    counter = 0
    pali = []
    def isPalindrome(listaWord):
        backup = copy.deepcopy(listaWord)
        backup.reverse()
        a = ''.join(backup)
        b = ''.join(listaWord)
        if(a == b):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    for i in range(len(lista)):
        current = [lista[i]]
        for j in range(i+1, len(lista)):
            current.append(lista[j])
            if(isPalindrome(current)):
                print(current)
                pali.append(current)
                counter+=1
    print(pali)
    return counter
print(ILEP("radar"))
```

The program is finding all palindromes correctly, but it assings them wrong to the list `pali`. Console:

```
['r', 'a', 'd', 'a', 'r']
['a', 'd', 'a']
[['r', 'a', 'd', 'a', 'r'], ['a', 'd', 'a', 'r']]
2
```

As U can see it prints palindromes `['r', 'a', 'd', 'a', 'r']` and `['a', 'd', 'a']`, but the list `pali` has got wrong value `[['r', 'a', 'd', 'a', 'r'], ['a', 'd', 'a', 'r']]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are changing your list `current` after appending to `pali`. You have to make a copy:

```
def is_palindrome(word):
    return word[::-1] == word

def ILEP(word):
    pali = []
    for i, ch in enumerate(word):
        current = [ch]
        for ch in word[i+1:]:
            current.append(ch)
            if is_palindrome(current):
                print(current)
                pali.append(current[:])
    print(pali)
    return len(pali)

print(ILEP("radar"))
```

Comment: can U explain to me the `is_palindrome` function?

Comment: `word[::-1]` gives a copy of `word` in reversed order.